# ListStepPlot PlotMarkers bug

Tags: plotting, bugs

There is a bug in `ListStepPlot`, which I reported to Wolfram and they are working on a fix. Until then, I wrote a simple workaround and thought I might share this with people, in case you encounter the same problem.

The bug appears when `ListStepPlot` is used with both `PlotMarkers` and `ScalingFunctions` set to non-default values. For example

```
ListStepPlot[Table[p Range[6], {p, {3, 7, 11, 13}}], "Center", 
  PlotMarkers -> Automatic, 
  ScalingFunctions -> "Log"
]
```

gives

[image: a plot with bad markers]

I provide a simple temporary bug-fix in my answer.

Answer (score 8):

A workaround is to apply the rule

```
BUGFIXRULEListStepPlotLog =
 GeometricTransformation[Inset[Style[m__], {0., 0.}], tr_] :>
  GeometricTransformation[Inset[Style[m], {0., 0.}], 
   If[#[[1, 2]] == 0, Nothing, {{#[[1, 1]], Log[#[[1, 2]]]}}] & /@ tr]
```

to the created figure. For example

```
ListStepPlot[Table[p {1, 2, 3, 0, 4, 5, 6}, {p, {3, 7, 11, 13}}], 
  "Center", PlotMarkers -> Automatic, 
  ScalingFunctions -> "Log"] /. BUGFIXRULEListStepPlotLog
```

gives

[image]

When other scaling functions are used, the bug-fix needs to be adjusted (replace `Log` by whatever is needed), but the general procedure should work in any case.